# Is it possible for a Spring Boot Kafka consumer to publish event and do a ksqldb INSERT within an atomic operation

Tags: apache-kafka, atomic, ksqldb, kafka-transactions-api

I have a spring boot application that is a consumer to topic-A. After it finish the business logic, it needs to publish a result to topic-B. At the same time, it needs to do a KSQL-DB INSERT operation to a existing ktable-01. e.g.
`INSERT INTO table_01(ROWTIME, KEY_COL, COL_A) VALUES (1510923225000, 'key', 'A');`

All the topics, Kstreams and Ktables are on one cluster of Kafka server running on-prem.
I need to make sure the publish to the result topic-B and insert to ktable-01 in one atomic transaction. If publish failed or insert failed, I want the Kafka transaction to keep the data integrity. I know the consistency is kept if

I checked online resources, cannot find a clear statement about this possibility. I know publish and subscribe can be controlled by Kafka transaction. Data integrity can also be kept within a stream/table operations. But, I doubt whether it is possible to still keep consistency between Kafka server and KsqlDB if they run on the same cluster.

Comment: In general, you'd produce to a topic directly, not issue a kSQL insert query. They are not one operation since kSQL is eventually consistent and running a different consumer thread than your own app. The location of the process doesnt matter (and you shouldnt run ksql on the broker machines anyway)

Comment: I understand that they are not 1 operation. But I wonder whether I can use Spring provided @Transactional annotation to put the 2 operations into 1 transaction and guarantee the INSERT call and publish call succeed or fail consistently.

Comment: That's not how that works since there would have to be a rollback operation in case the first method failed (which means at least two requests are done by Spring for any failure case). JPA with a transactional database natively has abort / rollback commands. As mentioned, you should first try to manually use `beginTransaction` of a kafka producer, not issue HTTP ksql requests.

Comment: I just did more dive into the KSQL implementation and found that the ksql requests are all done by HTTP calls to the KSQL DB Engine. So, there is no way to guarantee a REST call and a kafka publish to be consistent within one atomic operation like we had in XA. I think it is neither possible even use an external JTA like atomikos.

Comment: And I was trying to explain you don't need a http call at all for ksql. You only produce... Ksql will then consume that record